# Error: Webpack Compilation Error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request' in cypress

Tags: webpack, axios, cypress

I'm learning how use cypress. I'm running a simple test on the Bestbuy web page. But I wasn't able to load the page. It say a fix adding a piece of code releated to axios library (I took it from here https://github.com/request/request/issues/2738). But now I got an error of Webpack.
how fix the webpack error?

error message from cypress runner

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request' in '/Users/michelle/CypressNovember/cypress/e2e'
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:212:23)
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:303:9
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Watching._done (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:299:28)
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:213:21
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:919:5)
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:191:22
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:885:14
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:882:27
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at alreadyWritten (/Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:714:8)
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:802:19
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.5.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
```

This is my code including the axios code

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

describe("Set a defaul store of Bestbuy", () => {

    before("to load the page", () => {

    })

    //numbers right
    //Real city in US
    //city close to US
    //real state
    //state close to US
    it("Set a defaul store (Happy path)", () => {
        const request = require('request');
        const axios = require('axios');
        const url = 'http://www.bestbuy.com/';
        request({
            url: url,
            timeout: 5000,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "User-Agent": "axios/0.18.0"
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error)
                console.log(`request got ${response.statusCode}`);
            else
                console.error(`request got an error`, error);
        });

        axios.get(url).then((ret) => {
            console.log(`Axios got ${ret.status}`);
        });
        //cy.visit("https://www.bestbuy.com")
        cy.get(".location-zip-code-form-content input").type("22897")
        cy.get(".location-zip-code-form-content button").click()
    })

    it("empty zip")
    it("Use my current location")
    it("invalid zip")
    //not exist (only numbers but is not a real zip)
    //no good format, between parentesis, with a leter, special characters -> display an error message
    //short number -> display an error message
    //long number -> display an error message
    //correct zip but with a space at the end or at the begining -> should display results
    it("Use city name")
    //3 differt cities in US

    it("Base on category")
    it("filter by devices")

})
```

e2e.js

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example support/e2e.js is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

//codigo para ocultar los fetch de xhr
const app = window.top;
if (!app.document.head.querySelector("[data-hide-command-log-request]")) {
const style = app.document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML =".command-name-request, .command-name-xhr { display: none }"; style.setAttribute("data-hide-command-log-request", ""); app.document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    //this configure thet I can see files with extension js,jsx,ts,tsx, and spec in the cypress test runner
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,spec}'
  },
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cypressnovember",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "cypress.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

[My files tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnMXf.png)

I don't know if I need to change a path of a file or what to do

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to `require('request')` it is built in to Cypress.

Just add `cy.` in front of `request`.

I can't tell what you are trying to do, but here's a simple example.

```js
it("Set a default store (Happy path)", () => {
  const url = 'http://www.bestbuy.com/';
  cy.request({
    url, 
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "axios/0.18.0"
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
  .then(response => {
     if (response.statusCode >= 400)
       console.log(`request got ${response.statusCode}`)
     } else {
       expect(response.body).not.to.eq(undefined)
     }
  })
```

Ideally, you want to use `cy.visit()` instead

```js
it("Set a default store (Happy path)", () => {
  const url = 'http://www.bestbuy.com/';
  cy.visit({
    url, 
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "axios/0.18.0"
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })

  // now test the loaded page
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to run a small test on the Bestbuy web page.

Test: I set the default store by defining the zip code. 

But I'm not even able to load the web page. I'm blocked, in the fist thing that is trying to load the page

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I tried both, but both gave me timed out waiting. It works in to remove the Webpack Compilation Error, but I getting back to the start point, which is using just 


it.only("just open the page",()=>
    {
        cy.visit("https://www.bestbuy.com/")
    })

Comment: I'm gonna try another web page less big. This is taking more time, and I want to practice the functional testing first instead of dealing with loading test :)